# SQL insert not working in DGlux app

Tags: sql

I'm doing a very simple SQL insert, which was working fine, until I added a UID column and now it won't work. A SQL syntax checker said this code is bad, but I can't see it. What;s the obvious thing here I'm missing? I've checked spellings, column names and db name all match.

```
INSERT INTO
virtualTree (PATH, NPATH, PUID, NAME, LEVEL, INDEX, UID)
VALUES(
'/data/Mitsubishi/Sys Info',
'/downstream/dgapi/DSA_Dev/config/sysInfo',
'',
'Sys Info',
'1',
'1',
'1532750575860'
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify database you use.

Furthermore, saying that you got a message "this code is bad" is quite useless. Computers don't write poetry, so shouldn't you. There was probably a very specific error message, along with the error code. For example, Oracle might have told you `ORA-00904: : invalid identifier` which is way more clear than "this code is bad". I suggest you to be more specific.

The following example shows what happens when you try to create a table using "invalid" column names (because they might be reserved words). It is based on Oracle. I removed "valid" column names to keep it simpler.

```
SQL> create table virtualtree
  2    (level varchar2(20),
  3     index varchar2(20),
  4     uid   varchar2(20));
  (level varchar2(20),
   *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier


SQL> create table virtualtree
  2    (c_level varchar2(20),
  3     index varchar2(20),
  4     uid   varchar2(20));
   index varchar2(20),
   *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier


SQL> create table virtualtree
  2    (c_level varchar2(20),
  3     c_index varchar2(20),
  4     uid   varchar2(20));
   uid   varchar2(20))
   *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier


SQL> create table virtualtree
  2    (c_level varchar2(20),
  3     c_index varchar2(20),
  4     c_uid   varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL>
```

See? I couldn't create a table whose names were `LEVEL`, `INDEX`, `UID` - I had to modify them, somehow; I chose to add the `C_` prefix.

I suggest you try the same. If what you said is true, your database complains about the `UID` column name.

If it doesn't help, back to the beginning - post *actual* error code and message, as well as the database you use.

Comment: I'm not sure what the database is, so I didn't specify. I'm working in a software suite called DGlux, which gives you little action blocks that you execute your code in and return error messages. In the sql block I'm using there is an error message block, but it wasn't giving me an error, so I was unable to trace it, which was one of my frustrations. I had all ready created a virtualTree table and it was adding lines to the table using the existing query minus the UID column. So I thought there might have just been some syntax issue I was missing.

Comment: I think that LEVEL and INDEX are reserved words, as you said, it's just weird because the update query was working with them before I added the UID column. Dunno, I'll test it more on Monday. Thanks for writing despite my lack of detail.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know anything about DGlux. Though, it is somewhat strange that you don't know which database you use. How can you write any code without knowing which syntax to follow? Although SQLs are *similar*, they aren't *identical* so - what works in MS SQL Server doesn't have to work in Oracle. The same goes for column names you used - apparently, database you're connected to accepts LEVEL and INDEX as column names, but doesn't accept UID. For your own sake, it would help if you find out which database it really is.

Comment: I concur. Thanks

Comment: My boss showed me where the error messages actually show up in this program. Ha. Looks like the INT type couldn't handle the length of the input. Data conversion error converting "'1532968734482' (VIRTUALTREE: UID INT)"; SQL statement:INSERT INTO virtualTree (PATH,NPATH,PUID,NAME,LEVEL,IN...